# Issue faced when trying to add zooming(react-three-fiber)

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have this sample https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-sky-dome-forked-614gw?file=/src/index.js. But zooming not working even if I use enableZoom thus I really need your kind help on how I can fix it.

Please HELP

Answer (score 0):

Zoom actually does work. The problem is that the control's target is `(0, 0, 0`) and the position of your camera is already `(0, 0, 0.1)`. So there is not much room for zoom in anymore.